# File_put_content of various images and rename with count

Tags: php, file-put-contents

I have following code:

```
  $url = explode('\n', $urls);
  $count = 0;
  foreach($url as $image) {
  $img = 'c://wamp/www/www.mysite.com/uploads/images/cat1/image'.$count++.'.png';
    file_put_contents($img, $image);
    }
```

In variable $urls have many urls with images in format .png.

I try created foreach for each new image create, for example: image1.png, image2.png. It does not work:

Thanks for any help

Comment: *It does not work* - What doesn't work? Is it not counting properly? Are you getting an error?

Comment: This creates the image files named with the count properly.
But the images are empty when opened. I tried the suggestions below and also failed yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to save the image data in the file, you will need to retrieve it from the url:

```
 $url = explode('\n', $urls);
  $count = 0;
  foreach($url as $image) {
  $img = 'c://wamp/www/www.mysite.com/uploads/images/cat1/image'.$count++.'.png';
    file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($image));
   }
```

Comment: Thanks. Is creating a sequence of images correctly, but only the first image creates correctly.

Other images are empty and php appears error for all images:  Warning: file_get_contents(`https://urlimage`): failed to open stream: Invalid argument in C:\wamp\www\www.www.mysite.com\site\home.php on line 59

Comment: @Zeli have you tried opening the problem urls in a browser? Do they load OK?

Comment: yes the images normally carry when opened in the browser

Comment: Hard to help without seeing the actual urls. Maybe there are additional spaces after the line breaks? If so try `file_get_contents(trim($image))`

Comment: My guess is the linebreaks where actually \r\n .

Comment: @VolkerK Are yes, that could be it. Imposable to know for sure without seeing the actual file contents

Answer (score 1):

Your code

```
file_put_contents($img, $image);
```

will put the contents of $image, i.e. url, into the file, not the contents "behind" the url.
But instead of a string you can pass a stream resource as the parameter $data to file_put_contents.  So open the stream via fopen/http-wrapper, check the result and pass it to file_put_contents.

```
$url = explode('\n', $urls);
foreach($url as $count=>$image) {
    $img = 'c://wamp/www/www.mysite.com/uploads/images/cat1/image'.$count.'.png';
    $fp = fopen($image, 'rb');
    if ( !$fp ) {
        yourErrorHandler();
    }
    else {
        $result = file_put_contents($img, $fp);
        // check $result here....
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, It only saved the first image the others are not created and appears php errors. `Warning: fopen( `https://urlimage`): failed to open stream: Invalid argument in C:\wamp\www\www.www.mysite.com\site\home.php on line 60`  and `Fatal error: Call to undefined function yourErrorHandler() in C:\wamp\www\www.mysite.com\site\home.php on line 62`